# In SwiftUI, when the MyView popup sheet then dismissed, the MyView should be displayed instead of ListView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-sheet

Here is three view,ContentView,ListView and MyView。Click first bottom icon show ListView,then click NavigationLink display MyView.Click the button display sheet,dismiss the sheet the ListView displayed on the screen.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ListView().tabItem {
                        Label("list view", systemImage: "face.smiling")
                    }
                Text("list 2 content").tabItem {
                    Label("text", systemImage: "face.smiling")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHStack(alignment: .top) {
                LazyVStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                        Text("test")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet,
               onDismiss: didDismiss)
        {
            VStack {
                Text("License Agreement")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(50)
                Text("""
                    Terms and conditions go here.
                """)
                .padding(50)
                Button("Dismiss",
                       action: { isShowingSheet.toggle() })
            }
        }
    }

    func didDismiss() {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

In MyView sheet dismissed，should display MyView

Comment: A tab view should not be inside navigation view. The navigation view should be inside the tab.

Comment: Note, `NavigationView` is deprecated, you should use `NavigationStack` instead.

Comment: I need support iOS14, NavigationStack support iOS16+.

Comment: Move navigation view  inside the tab view,the problem is not solved.

Comment: This issue only occurs on iOS17, iOS16 has no issues

Comment: Since you needed it to work on iOS 14 (And did not know it before) I've updated the code in the answer below. It should work fine now. I tested it on iOS 15.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me if you re-organise the hierarchy as suggested in the comments and put the `NavigationView` inside the `TabView`, instead of vice versa.

After the sheet is dismissed, `MyView` can be seen again. However, it immediately navigates back to `ListView` due to the `.onDismiss` parameter to the `.sheet` modifier. So if you don't want it to navigate back (perhaps for testing), remove the `.onDismiss` parameter, or comment out the body of `didDismiss`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ListView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("list view", systemImage: "face.smiling")
            }
            Text(
                "list 2 content"
            )
            .tabItem {
                Label("text", systemImage: "face.smiling")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ListView").font(.largeTitle)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .top) {
                    LazyVStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                            Text("Go to MyView")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("MyView").font(.largeTitle)
            Spacer()
            Button("Show Sheet") { isShowingSheet.toggle() }
            Spacer()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, onDismiss: didDismiss) {
            VStack {
                Text("License Agreement")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(50)
                Text("""
                Terms and conditions go here.
            """)
                .padding(50)
                Button("Dismiss") { isShowingSheet.toggle() }
            }
        }
    }

    func didDismiss() {
        // Don't navigate back
        // presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. First off, if you are on iOS 17+ you need to use a NavigationStack instead of the soon to be deprecated NavigationView since it was the latter causing issues. Otherwise, you can use the NavigationView that I tested on iOS 15.5 and works fine in this scenario. Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            NavigationStack {
                TabViewNavigation()
            }
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                TabViewNavigation()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func TabViewNavigation() -> some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ListView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("list view", systemImage: "face.smiling")
                }
                .tag(1)
            Text("list 2 content").tabItem {
                Label("text", systemImage: "face.smiling")
            }
            .tag(2)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd suggest you to also keep track of the current selected tab using the selection property in the TabView constructor like I did above.
Then, in MyView, do not use the onDismiss, rather use the isShowing sheet State variable to show or hide the sheet this way:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isShowingSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show Sheet")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, onDismiss: {
            isShowingSheet = false
        })
        {
            VStack {
                Text("License Agreement")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(50)
                Text("""
                    Terms and conditions go here.
                """)
                .padding(50)
                Button("Dismiss", action: {
                    isShowingSheet = false
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    func didDismiss() {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Hope I was able to help you. Let me know if that worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can eliminate the use of ***@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode*** and utilize the isShowingSheet variable itself for sheet presentation and dismissal. Update the code from:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, onDismiss: didDismiss)
```

to:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet)
```

Additionally, replace NavigationView with NavigationStack.